# Downvoting in response to closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, down-votes

After a question was recently closed the poster of said question started downvoting posts of everybody participating in the closure of his question.

Is such behavior considered appropriate? If not is there anything other users should do if such behavior is noticed?

In case anybody wonder how I could deduce what had happened, this is what I saw: Within the first 10 minutes after the question was closed each person participating in the closure had one old post downvoted. That does not look like a coincidence at all. Moreover the reputation of the person who had asked the closed question had dropped by as many points as the number of answers among the downvoted posts. (I can provide a link to the closed question if really necessary, but I think it might be better if I leave that out.)

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: @EEAA http://serverfault.com/q/771169/214507

Comment: I don't have time to do research now, but in short, hopefully the serial dv algorithm will catch this and reverse the votes.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right question? I could not find a bunch of people who had participated in that question and been downvoted elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can confirm I got a downvote (on http://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http) around the same time as the poster of that question's little rage fit.

Comment: @ceejayoz You appear to be the only one. I could not find anyone else.

Comment: @MichaelHampton No look at http://serverfault.com/users/118258/hopelessn00b?tab=reputation http://serverfault.com/users/584/ceejayoz?tab=reputation http://serverfault.com/users/214507/kasperd?tab=reputation http://serverfault.com/users/8897/sven?tab=reputation all four shows a downvote at that time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton HopelessN00b got a DV on http://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam/415564#415564 and kasperd got a DV on http://serverfault.com/questions/595366/is-it-safe-for-a-production-server-to-have-make-installed/595379#595379. All three DVs took place 57 minutes ago.

Comment: Ohh, I see. The downvotes are on everyone who closed the question. I was looking at the commenters.

Comment: Yeah, the close voters. One for Sven at http://serverfault.com/questions/33977/192-168-1-x-more-exploitable/33988#33988 as well.

Comment: @EEAA Unless they've updated it significantly, the serial d/v script won't catch this kind of retaliatory voting.  Deleting the account would reverse the votes, though. :)

Comment: @HopelessN00b Ahh, ok. Good to know.

Comment: Maybe we should take him up on his word. Quoting his comment (deleted by me): `You may go ahead and close/delete my profile who cares!!`

Comment: @Sven Sure sounds like permission to me.  Hell, given his last name, that even sounds like the way people who share his presumptive homeland tend to phrase requests, so I'd choose to interpret it as such.

Comment: @Sven can you unblock it so we can keep down voting?  Just it seems to get to him and i think it would be funny to exhaust his rep purrty please *cute kitten face*

Comment: @ash: Most certainly no.

Comment: @ash If I understand correctly how the system works, that would cause the question to be deleted in a few days after which he gets the reputation back.

Comment: @kasperd likely, although I was hoping it was seen for the joke it was.  I think Sven is angry with me.

Comment: @ash Your comment could easily be interpreted as entirely serious.

Answer (score 13):

> After a question was recently closed the poster of said question started downvoting posts of everybody participating in the closure of his question.
>
> Is such behavior considered appropriate?

No, it's not.  Report it (like you did with this thread), and the mods will take a look.  It's been a while, but I recall there being a suspension category for this kind of behavior.  He certainly wouldn't be first to get a time-out for retaliatory voting.

On a related note, this type of poster is just another reason to think twice about commenting on bad, downvoted questions.  You end up becoming the target of some asshole's misplaced anger a lot more often than anything constructive comes of it.  ***Better to just downvote, (and/or) vote to close, shake your head at the fail and move on.***

Comment: Not sure about the last sentence. Just down-vote is anonymous, but does not provide any constructive feedback. It should not be used by default. There are such people who behave this way, but still most of them are eager to learn and improve (at least a bit) and just down-vote is frustrating.